# Recover incomplete DAR archive

Tags: backup, archiving

I have a backup, at least part of it, in an incomplete DAR archive. 
This means I have the first n of x slices, but not the end which would contain the catalogue.

```
$ dar -l mydararchive
Error met while opening the last slice: This is an old archive, it can only be opened starting by the first slice. Trying to open the archive using the first slice...
FATAL error, aborting operation
Badly formatted terminator, cannot extract catalogue location:
```

Unfortunately the archive was not created with the necessary escape sequences used for sequential-read.

```
$ dar --sequential-read -l mydararchive
FATAL error, aborting operation
Sequential read asked, but this archive is flagged to not have the necessary embedded escape sequences for that operation, aborting
```

Is there any way around this, maybe some analysis tool which finds and extracts data from an incomplete dar archive?