# Recover DAR Archive Slices using an Isolated Catalogue

Tags: backup, data-recovery, cygwin, archiving

I have a [DAR archive](http://dar.linux.free.fr/) of 10 slices. Having lost the last slice, how can the files in the 9 intact slices be recovered. (*The catalogue of the whole archive is contained in the last slice.*)

There is a similar question:

> [Recover incomplete DAR archive](https://superuser.com/questions/718863/recover-incomplete-dar-archive)

The difference is a separate **isolated catalogue is available** in my case.

---

[DAR Tutorial](http://dar.sourceforge.net/doc/Tutorial.html) says:

> Second, we can use the isolated catalogue as backup of the internal
>   catalogue if it get corrupted. Well to face to data corruption the
>   best solution ever invented is Parchive, an autonomous program that
>   builds parity file (same mechanism as the one used for RAID disks) for
>   a given file. Here we can use Parchive to create a parity file for
>   each slice. So, assuming you lack Parchive, and that you failed
>   reading the full backup because the usb key is corrupted in the part
>   used to store the internal catalogue, you can use an isolated
>   catalogue as rescue:
>
> ```
> dar -x linux_full -A /root/CAT_linux_full ...
> dar -d linux_full -A /root/CAT_linux_full ...
> dar -t linux_full -A /root/CAT_linux_full ...
> dar -l /root/CAT_linux_full
> ```

---

Command line output:

```
C:\dar64-2.6.5>dar.exe -x "/cygdrive/d/theArchive" -A "cygdrive/d/theCatalog"
The last file of the set is not present in file:///cygdrive/d , please provide it. [return = YES | Esc = NO]
Continuing...
The last file of the set is not present in file:///cygdrive/d , please provide it. [return = YES | Esc = NO]
Escaping...
Final memory cleanup...
Aborting program. User refused to continue while asking: The last file of the set is not present in file:///cygdrive/d , please provide it.
```

I'm in Windows and apparently, DAR requires cygwin paths as mentioned above. (*I'm not much familiar with either dar or cygwin*)

dar seems to ignore the isolated catalog and refuses to give-up looking for the last slice. So, I duplicated the 9th slice and renamed it as the 10th. Still the same response as above.

I really hope someone can figure this out. Any command line arguments would be very much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

After digging through mailing-lists of DAR project, it turns out adding **[--sequential-read](https://sourceforge.net/p/dar/mailman/message/28050634/)** can prevent DAR from getting stuck requesting for the missing slices.

```
C:\dar64-2.6.5>dar.exe -x "/cygdrive/d/theArchive" --sequential-read -A "/cygdrive/d/theCatalog"
theArchive.10.dar is required for further operation, please provide the file. [return = YES | Esc = NO]
Escaping...
/cygdrive/z/Image11.jpg not restored (user choice)
```

Most of the files of the archive were recovered!

However, a recovered file was corrupted - probably a file spanning into the missing slice.